# CSS UL LI Vertical Menu

Tags: html, css, menu, html-lists

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" Theme="SF" CodeBehind="ULLITest.aspx.cs" Inherits="ClickDoors_WebApp.ULLITest" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">    

        #Menu
        {
            padding:0;
            margin:0;
            list-style-type:none;
            font-size:13px;
            color:#717171;
            width:100%;
        }

        #Menu li
        {
            border-bottom:1px solid #eeeeee;
            padding:7px 10px 7px 10px;
        }

        #Menu li:hover
        {
            color:White;
            background-color:#ffcc00;
        }

        #Menu a:link
        {
            color:#717171;
            text-decoration:none;
        }

        #Menu a:hover
        {
            color:White;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <form id="form1" runat="server">

    <div>
        <ul id="Menu">
            <li><a href="#">Internal Doors</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Prefinished Internal Doors</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">External Doors</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Internal Pair [French Doors]</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">External Pair [French Doors]</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Custom Size Doors</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Door Frames</a></li>
            <li>Test</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

When i hover over it background-color is changed immediately but font color remains same until i hover over text.

In short i want my menu to behave similar to stackoverflows menu (Questions Tags Users....)

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd do it like this:

1. Set your `<a>` tags to `display:block`
2. Remove the padding from your `<li>`'s (make it `padding:0px`)
3. Re-add the padding to your `<a>` tags `padding:7px 10px 7px 10px;`
4. Add `background-color:#ffcc00;` to `#Menu a:hover`
5. Get rid of `#Menu li:hover`

Answer (score 3):

need to add `#Menu li:hover a {color:White;}` This will set white color for `a` when a `li` is hovered.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/Nceef/

Answer (score 1):

Give this css properties:

```
#Menu a {display:block}
#Menu a:hover,active {color:#text-color;background:#background-color;}
```

Comment: The problem with other solutions, is that the link will appear as hovered even if it is still not clikcable, so it can lead to bad user experience.

Answer (score 1):

```
#Menu li
{
    border-bottom:1px solid #eeeeee;
}

#Menu li a:hover
{
    color:White;
    background-color:#ffcc00;
}

#Menu a:link
{
    color:#717171;
    text-decoration:none;
    display:block;
    padding: 7px 10px;
}
```

Only drawback of this method is your elements in the list that arent anchors wont be padded correctly.

**Demo**

http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/F6UGv/